# I integrated DropBox SDK and try to download file but getting fail to download some time

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Please help me,
I integrated DropBox SDK and getting failed downloading some time.

at that time this method called.

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the circumstances around the call, which you have provided no information about, nor have you given any details as to the failure.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Thanks for reply, Right now i am not getting this but my application user getting Alert which i putted in `- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be help you.
Check you internet connection and try to use call this method in main thread if you are not calling in background.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self restClient] loadFile:path intoPath:destinationPath];
    });
```